# How to make material design toolbar having different height at right and left?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

i want to make a toolbar like shown in the image. i have search a lot but could not find any clue how to make **toolbar having different height at right and left**.

i would be thankful if someone give any idea or refer any blog.

**I want a toolbar at an angle as shown in image below.**

[image]

Comment: you can't give height like this to `Toolbar` my  suggestion is take background image and set it to `Toobar`

Comment: ok thanks for your reply.

Comment: you do not need to make a toolbar for that. just use any viewGroup that fulfils your need. and set a background image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom view that splits layout diagonally with different child views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338840/custom-view-that-splits-layout-diagonally-with-different-child-views)

Answer (score 1):

You can use layerlist to give left heigh and right height to buttons

this is a working example

Here is the shape file called *`arrow_shape.xml`*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size 
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="#5EB888" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="-40dp"
    android:bottom="65dp"
    android:right="-30dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item
    android:top="65dp"
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-30dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Then use it as button's background, for example

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_shape"/>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

More info on *`Layer-List`* you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).