# Drawing a custom shape to load Image as recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to make a custom layout like below view.

In this view I want to make `TextView` half sliced from one end and another `ImageView` from another end. So please tell me how to make such custom `TextView` and `ImageView` with diagonal clipped from one side.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34898112/3360307) answer you can use this view and customize it horizontally instead of vertical.
Or you can also check for [this](https://gist.github.com/ZieIony/8480b2d335c1aeb51167) code as well which something like below image.
Reference also available [here](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/create-diagonal-cut-view-in-android-5a376eca6a1c)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ok i will try it.